# For Downloading Mulesoft Anypoint Studio visible that Download 30 day free trial.So How to use after 30 Days?

Tags: mule, soa, esb, anypoint-studio

For Downloading Mulesoft Anypoint Studio visible that Download 30 day free trial.So How to use after 30 Days?

[image]

Comment: You could, like, buy it?

Comment: This isn't really a good place to ask this question. This is a q&A site for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

The 30 day free trial is not actually for Anypoint Studio, but for Mule standalone container. The studio will continue to work indefinitely, but not the standalone Mule container for dev, production releases etc.

After 30 days the container will stop running your applications but you can continue to develop in Anypoint Studio. To continue using the standalone container/s you will need to purchase an Enterprise license from Mulesoft. You can contact them via their website. You can also use the Community Edition which is free, it uses the same Studio, but you need to make sure you are using the Community runtime so that when it comes to deployment you are not using any Enterprise features.

Answer (score -2):

The 30 day trail version is for only the cloudhub part. where after 30 days you can't do any changes or work with your anypoint cloudhub account. either you can work in you anypoint platform in local.